# downcast to AVAssetDownloadURLSession fails

Tags: ios, avassetdownloadtask

I'm creating an `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`

here's my code:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "background")
let avSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: config, assetDownloadDelegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

let any : Any = avSession
print("any as? AVAssetDownloadURLSession \(any as? AVAssetDownloadURLSession)") // always returns nil
```

Now, if I print out `avSession`, it says it is an `__NSURLBackgroundSession`, not an `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`. If I assign `avSession` to another variable (in this case an Any), and then downcast it later, it fails.

This is a real problem because I do need to do exactly this. Why can't I downcast this without failing? If I inspect the memory address of `avSession`, and then inspect any in the debugger, they both have the same address. But it is most certainly (according to the debugger, and the runtime itself) not an `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Could you explain why you would need the cast? Just to figure out if another solution might be possible.

Comment: After I create the `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`, I need to pass it off to another library, and this library doesn't know anything about `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`. At a later time when I need to use it, and I try and downcast the value, it fails.

Comment: And why would you not just use a variable of the right type? I.e.: why do you choose to assign to a variable of the type `Any` instead of `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to keep the code small to demonstrate the odd behavior. But I didn't really explain the problem too well, apologies for that. What's happening is that I am creating the object just fine. But I need do something with it later, not right away.   I'm using a 3rd party library that doesn't know anything about `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`, but I need to pass this newly created object to it, so that I block gets executed later. It's at that point, in that block, when I try and downcast this object to `AVAssetDownloadURLSession` where things go bad. The code above just demonstrates it.

Comment: As far as I can see it is not possible to downcast the __NSURLBackgroundSession to AVAssetDownloadURLSession. I've tried it many different ways, but no success. So I think if you really want to create the object first and later re-use, perhaps instead of storing the object, you could store the parameters needed to create the object.

Comment: I suggest filing this as a bug with Apple.

Comment: Thanks. filed. http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5029435040333824